# Verificar que un script en Python se esté ejecutando y que si no lo está, se ejecute

Tags: python, linux, bash

Este es mi `script` en Phyton:

```
import os
import sys

pid = str(os.getpid())
pidfile = "/tmp/mydaemon.pid"

if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
        print("%s el archivo ya existe, cerrando el proceso" % pidfile)
        sys.exit()
file(pidfile, "w").write(pid)

try:
        while(True):
                print("Soy un proceso de python ejecutandose en tiempo real")
finally:
        os.unlink(pidfile)
```

Y este es mi `script` en bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f /tmp/mydaemon.pid ]; then
        echo "El proceso no se está ejecutando\r\n"
        echo "Ejecutando proceso...\r\n"
        python python.py
fi
        echo "El proceso ya se está ejecutando"
```

Lo que quiero es que esté "escuchando" si el `script` de Python se está ejecutando, y si **NO** lo está haciendo que lo ejecuté, con el código anterior ejecuto mi Python correctamente pero si mato el proceso mediante un `$ sudo kill PID` se cierra y no lo vuelve a ejecutar ¿Qué debo corregir para solucionar mi problema?

Comment: Hay una herramienta mejor para lo que quieres. Se llama Supervisord, que es un demonio que vigila que un programa se ejecute siempre y si falla, lo arranca de nuevo. Te da controles de ejecutar, parar y reiniciar. Estoy en el teléfono, pero busca supervisord en Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizá sería más cómodo que tu script de `bash` ejecute de manera permanente tu script python de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  echo "El proceso no se está ejecutando\r\n"
  echo "Ejecutando proceso...\r\n"
  python python.py
  case $? in
  137|143)
    # El script python ha finalizado por recibir un "kill" normal (TERM)
    # o un kill -9 (KILL), repetimos el bucle
    continue
    ;;
  *)
    # El script python ha terminado por otro motivo, decidir si salir
    # o repetir el bucle indefinidamente
    break
    ;;
  exac
done
```

El funcionamiento se basa en un bucle infinito que sólo es interrumpido si el script python no recibió un `kill PID` o `kill -9 PID`. En otro caso detiene la ejecución del script `bash`.

Si quieres que SIEMPRE se esté ejecutando termine como termine el script de python, entonces simplemente quita el bloque `case/esac`.

---

Otra solución, comprobar que exista un proceso con el PID almacenado:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  if [ -f "/tmp/mydaemon.pid" ] && kill -0 $(cat "/tmp/mydaemon.pid")
  then
    echo "Todo en orden, no es necesario ejecutar nada"
  else
    echo "El proceso no se está ejecutando\r\n"
    echo "Ejecutando proceso...\r\n"
    python python.py
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Ojo, en este ejemplo estamos mezclando un proceso vigía (`watchdog`) con un bucle infinito... si supiera qué quieres hacer, cuáles son tus intenciones, podría ayudarte a elegir la mejor forma de implementar la solución.

---

Por último, puedes delegar ese trabajo al proceso [`init`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/init).

Puedes crear un archivo llamado `/etc/init/tuscript.conf` para agregar las siguientes líneas:

```
description "Mi script de python"
start on runlevel [2345]
exec /ruta/a/tu/script.py
respawn
```

(Ojo, este método no lo he usado nunca desde que han cambiado la configuración de `/etc/inittab` al directorio `/etc/init/`).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la segunda solución me funcionó a la perfección, solo añadí esta línea: `os.unlink(pidfile)` a mi `Python` bajo el `if os.path.isfile(pidfile):` y ahora si le doy un `$ kill PID` al proceso me lo renueva en otro y lo mantiene ejecutando sin problemas! :D

Comment: Ups, tengo un error en el código. Hay que poner un `sleep 1` para evitar que el bucle infinito consuma el 100% de una de tus CPUs. Ya lo he editado.